# How can I add an Double_Click Event Handler to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I work with VisualStudio19, C# and WPF. I have a method to copy the selected Datarow from Table one, to Table two with a button_click, but now I want to copy the row when I double click it. I will use the same method as button_click for that so I need only an Eventhandler which start my method on doubleclick

The Tables:

```
       public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //First Table for all values
        tableAllVar.Columns.Add("Parameter", typeof(string));
        tableAllVar.Columns.Add("Adresse", typeof(string));
        tableAllVar.Columns.Add("Groesse", typeof(string));
        dgTable1.ItemsSource = tableAllVar.DefaultView;

        //second Table for selected values
        tableSelectedVar.Columns.Add("Parameter", typeof(string));
        tableSelectedVar.Columns.Add("Adresse", typeof(string));
        tableSelectedVar.Columns.Add("Groesse", typeof(string));
        dgTable2.ItemsSource = tableSelectedVar.DefaultView;
    }
```

The two Tables left ist the table I want to copy the row and right is the aimtable for the row.

[image]

My method to copy the selected Datarow with a Button

```
        private void ButtonAddVar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] daten = new string[3];
        if (dgTable1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            DataRowView datarow = (DataRowView)dgTable1.SelectedItem;
            daten[0] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[0];
            daten[1] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[1];
            daten[2] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[2];
            bool rowExists = ContainDataRowInDataTable(tableSelectedVar, datarow.Row);
            if (rowExists == false)
            {
                tableSelectedVar.Rows.Add(daten[0], daten[1], daten[2]);
                //anzahl++;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Die Variable ist bereits Teil der Variablenüberwachung", null, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte eine Variable aus der linken Liste mit der Maus auswählen",null,MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
```

And here the way i create my Datagrid in the xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="dgTable1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="180" Margin="5,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="6" ColumnHeaderHeight="15" IsReadOnly="True"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Binding="{Binding Path=Parameter}"  Width="auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adresse" Binding="{Binding Path=Adresse}" Width="auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Größe" Binding="{Binding Path=Größe}" Width="auto"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I saw that the DataGrid has an Eventhandler for Double_Click but i don't know how i can use them for the DataTable?
When i can't use them for Table how can i make a new Eventhandler for that event?

Comment: Move the logic to a new method and call it in both button_click and MouseDoubleClick of DataGrid.

Comment: When i make a double click on a tablerow my Eventhandler from the DataGrid didn't start, because i click in the Table and not in the Grid so that don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by table and grid? Dont you use 2 DataGrids?

Comment: I use for every Table a new Datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know DataGrid has a Double_Click  Eventhandler
for copy one row you can use selected row property.

```
 private void dgTable1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
 string[] daten = new string[3];
 if (dgTable1.SelectedItem != null)
 {
 DataRowView datarow = (DataRowView)dgTable1.SelectedItem;
 daten[0] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[0];
 daten[1] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[1];
 daten[2] = (string)datarow.Row.ItemArray[2];                            
 }
 else
 MessageBox.Show("please select again");
 }
```